# New User With Root Access and Without Sudo

Tags: permissions, root

I Know about the security risk and I know about sudo, sudo su, sudo -i and the sudoers file but what I need is to create a new user (not root user) with the root privilage without having to use sudo at all. how to do that ? and don't give me an altrnative ways please
thank you

Comment: If you know about the security risks, then why do it. There are (almost) never a reason to be permanently logged in with root-rights.

Comment: if you use virtualbox you will understand :)

Comment: I have used VirtualBox .. I still don't understand. Please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **It is recommended not to use another user as root and just use sudo permissions.**
2. You can simply add user by `sudo adduser <username>`.
3. You can change the uid and gid to root uid and gid by using `sudo nano /etc/passwd`

   - you will see users at the same syntax as this example:
   - `root:!:0:0::/:/usr/bin/bash`
   - `newroot:x:1001:1002:,,,:/home/newroot:/bin/bash`
   - change your new user uid and gid to the same as root `newroot:x:0:0:,,,:/home/newroot:/bin/bash`
4. Look for the user you created and change the uid and gid to the same as root gid and uid.
5. To look what the uid and gid of the root you can just look in the same file at the root user or use the command `id root`.

   - on the most of the distributions the uid and gid of the root is 0.
6. **I AM SAYING AGAIN IT IS NOT RECOMMENDED TO PUT ANOTHER USER AS ROOT**

   - you can get the same permissions by using sudo command.
7. To give you new user the sudo permissions **wich is recommended then the first part on my answer** you can simply make it by:

   - `sudo useradd <NEWUSER>`
   - `sudo usermod -a -G sudo <NEWUSERNAME>`
   - the -a for not overwriting and deleting the "old" groups of the user.

Comment: The system does not recoginize the new user and it think that it is the root user .. is there a way around that ?

Comment: what about groups for example ? can I add the new user to the root group

Comment: not helpful about what I asked you :(

Comment: try to change the gid and uid on the /etc/passwd without changing the path that will work out, (i just did on my ubuntu)

Comment: what if I'm running a service as root and wanted to drop permissions ?